# “The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few”

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, determiners, quantifiers

Think of [Star Trek's quote](https://www.theobjectivestandard.com/2013/09/spocks-illogic-the-needs-of-the-many-outweigh-the-needs-of-the-few/):

> “The needs of **the many** outweigh the needs of **the few**” (or “the one”)

In the context of Star Trek, does **the many/few** refer to a specific group of many/few beings or many/few beings in general?

If it's the former, can the same phrase refer to the latter in a different context?

If it's the latter, can the same phrase refer to the former in a different context?

Comment: I have only a passing knowledge of _Star Trek_, but the idea of sacrificing one person to save the community is by no means new. In John 11:50 Caiaphas says (referring to Jesus), "You do not realize that it is better for you that one man die for the people than that the whole nation perish."

Comment: Just a guess, but it was probably intentionally ambiguous. Or the latter—think of Spock—is he a member of the same group (by loyalty, perhaps) as, e.g., Kirk?

Comment: @Xanne I'd say he's a member of the same group of sentient beings or a member of Starfleet.

Comment: This feels context-dependent, even within the universe. Spock and Kirk may mean different things in The Wrath of Khan; Tuvok may mean something yet different in the series finale of Voyager. And of course it's possible the characters in universe don't think so exclusively about many/few; it can reflect both their specific situation and general utilitarian practice at the same time. As asked, this feels more like a science fiction question, without a clear answer for usage.

Comment: It refers to beings in general here; it's presented as an aphorism. But you could make it more specific by context: Maybe you're talking about humans but not  vulcans. Or maybe you're talking about tribbles but not human(oid)s.

Comment: In the context of Star Trek, how many episodes should we watch to grasp whether the many/few refer to a specific group or many/few beings in general?

Whether or not it's the former, the same phrase can refer to the latter, until you explain a context where it can't.

Whether or not it's the latter, the same phrase can refer to the former, until you explain a context where it can't.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Does 'the one' in 'or the one' feel context-dependent as well?

Comment: Yes. A speaker could mean "the one" in general as well as one or both of them.

Comment: It only affects those who live in a gravity field; otherwise the _outweigh_ metaphor is impossible.